# Can Latin Square combine between- and within-subject design?

Tags: experiment-design, psychology, random-allocation, latin-square

I´m doing an experiment and I´m not entirely sure if my design is still the Latin Square Design. 
I have 2 independent variables:

`medium` and `platform` with `3` values each:

- `medium`: `FAZ`, `SZ`, `OM`
- `platform`: `Facebook`, `Print`, `Online`

I will divide my participants in 3 groups based on my first variable `medium`, so I will have the following groups:

- `Group 1` - `FAZ`
- `Group 2` - `SZ`
- `Group 3` - `OM`

In each Group each participant will receive stimuli for every `platform`: `Facebook`, `Print` and`Online`.

They will receive an article posted on each of the platforms to read.

For example: Participant 1 get 1 article from `Facebook`, 1 article from `Print` and 1 article in `Online`.

All of the texts are from same `medium`, for example `FAZ`, and all the texts are different for each `platform` of one `medium`, but the same on the same `platform` type for all `mediums`:

1 text for all 3 `Facebook`-versions, 1 text for all 3 `Print`-versions und 1 text for all 3 `Online`-versions, so I have 3 articles - 1 for each `platform` independent of the `medium`.

I also will make a rotation for each group, so every participant will get the articles for one `medium` in different order.

I am now confused if I can still call it Latin Square or if it is just 3x3 Design, because I will have 3 independent groups (between-subject) and in each of these groups I have other groups (within-subject).

Or do i have 3 latin squares now?

I hope my setup is clear, 
Thanks in advance